# How to send data to bluetooth LE in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, swift4

I am newbie to bluetooth communication. My task is to write data to bluetooth with commonand.
The commonand is `0x61` and I need to pass `01-02-03-04` 4 byte value to it.
I have recognized charcteristics.

I want answer in swift 4.

```
  let string = "0xB101020304"
                    let _data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)


                    self.peripheral?.writeValue(ofCharac: ser, value: _data!, completion: { (reult) in
                        switch result{
                        case .success(let value):
                            print(value)
                            print("wow")
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    })
```

Comment: Can you please show the relevant code that you have tried and indicate your specific problem. Your question as it stands is too broad

Comment: @Paulw11 I have shared some code

Comment: The code you have there is sending the string. If you want to send the byte values then you will need to declare an array of bytes and send that

Comment: can you please share the script? @Paulw11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have will send the bytes that represent the string `"0xB101020304"`, but presumably you want to send the bytes B1 01 02 03 04.

```
let dataBytes:[UInt8] = [0xB1,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04]

let data = Data(bytes: dataBytes)

self.peripheral?.writeValue(ofCharac: ser, value: data, completion: { (result) in
    switch result {
        case .success(let value):
            print(value)
            print("wow")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
})
```